# WindowBuilder palette with no components

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, ubuntu, windowbuilder

I recently installed windowBuilder tools on my Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler). When I try to do some work on layout designer, then no components appears on my palette window. Only some few components like "Layouts-->layout" or "Swing Actions --> new", in front of a expected amount of them. All folders are empty or with only one or two components.

I reinstalled my Eclipse twice, my "windowbuilder tools" and its components and finally I refresed my Java JDK installation, with no success.

I have Ubuntu "Linux version 3.2.0-51-generic (buildd@allspice) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #77-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 24 20:18:19 UTC 2013" and java JDK 1.7.0_45.

Amazingly, when I select "palette manager" option on palette's contextual menu, all components appears available. I.e, under "components" folder appears from about 20 available  (and selected) controls, but when I return to editor, I have no components.

I'm a little confused and I have no idea why I can't get the components.

Thanks in advanced, 
Manel

Answer (score 2):

Solved: I think the problem comes from Kepler and WindowBuilder integration. I have downgraded my Eclipse version from Kepler to Juno and installed WindowBuilder for Juno and the problem was completely solved. All the other ways I'have been tried with Kepler(testing with several distributions, changing settings, language, reinstalling, etc...) was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is related to how Eclipse decides to open a class in WindowBuilder. To solve the problem:

1. Make sure you have installed the "Swing Designer" Eclipse Plugin (or also the "SWT Designer").
2. Make sure that in `Eclipse => Preference => WindowBuilder` the Option "Associate WindowBuilder editor with automatically recognized  Java GUI files" is checked on.
3. If your file is not automatically opened with WindowBuilder, right-click on the file and select `Open With => WindowBuilder Editor`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem much more recently.  I had tried installing WindowBuilder 1.9.3 for Eclipse 2020-03 from https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php but couldn't get it to work.

First, when I clicked on the Design tab, I would only see "Eclipse is running under 0, but this Java project has a 9 Java compliance level".  I eventually got past that by reconciling the JDK versions using the answer at: https://superuser.com/questions/661718/os-x-eclipse-windowbuilder-incompatible-java-versions.

After that it would fire up, but the Design window would come up empty, no components in the Palette.  The solution that finally worked was to reinstall WindowBuilder from the Marketplace at https://marketplace.eclipse.org.